# New line not printing by using nl2br in PHP and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to solve a new line issue in CodeIgniter. My variable is set as below

```
$ba='hi\r\nhello';
```

When I try to print it like this

```
echo nl2br($ba);
```

It's not converting `\r\n` to a new line. After a whole day of searching I found out that this is because my variable is with `'` not `"`

I've also tried to use `preg_replace` but it's the same

```
preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>',$ba);
```

But I can't change this so how do I fix this issue?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: You tried `$ba="hi\r\nhello";` and this was no good?

Comment: Why can't you change from `'` to `"`? Just curious.

Comment: actually value of variable is coming from some complicated process and i cant simply change it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`"\n"` is not the same as `'\n'`**! This is your basic problem. You are not trying to replace what you think you are

`"\n"` is converted in to a line feed or ASCII 13

`'\n'` is the character `\` then the character `n`

```
$ba='hi\r\nhello';
$ba=str_replace('\r\n','<br>',$ba);

echo $ba; // hi<br>hello
```

to use a regular expression:

as `\` is an escape character you need to triple it:

`$ba=preg_replace('#\\\r\\\n|\\\r|\\\n#','<br/>',$ba);`

Comment: hi, thx for reply but preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n/','<br/>',$ba); is not working too...